# PHP Import WP Terms child term into custom post type

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, import, categories

I have created a import tool to import data from a json file to create posts in my custom post type. It all works well and I can import acf fields as well as assigned terms. My question is, how can I import child term assigned to the term.

I have two variables right now that collects the data. I would like the have the variable eventCategoryChildName to assign its vaule as a child term to eventCategoryID

```
  $eventCategoryChildName = $ev['OfficialCity'];
  $eventCategoryId = $ev['RegionID'];
```

Here is how the import of terms functions right now without child terms:

```
 // set category terms
 $cat_ids = $eventCategoryName;
 // Add these categories, note the last argument is true.
 wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cat_ids, 'lan', true );
```

Edit:

So I managed to import the child associated to the right parents but they are not checked to the post

```
    // set category terms
    $cat_ids = $eventCategoryName;

    // Import category name
    $term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cat_ids, 'lan', true );

    $parent_term = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cat_ids, 'lan', true );

    // Check terms import for errors
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_taxonomy_ids ) ) {
        // There was an error somewhere and the terms couldn't be set.
        echo $return->get_error_message();
    } else {
        // Success! These categories were added to the post.
    }


    $parent_term = term_exists( $eventCategoryName, 'lan' ); 
    wp_insert_term(
      $eventCategoryChildName,                // Customize as you wish
      'lan',
      array(
          'parent'      => $parent_term['term_id'],
          'slug'        => $eventCategoryChildName  // Customize as you wish
      )
    );

    if ( !is_wp_error( $child_term_result ) ) {
      wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $child_term_result['term_id'], 'lan', true );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should check the result of `wp_set_object_terms`, to see if an error was returned:

```
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cat_ids, 'lan', true );
if ( is_wp_error( $term_taxonomy_ids ) ) {
    // There was an error somewhere and the terms couldn't be set.
    echo $return->get_error_message();
} else {
    // Success! These categories were added to the post.
}
```

Then, the term you want to add may not exists. In such case, `wp_set_object_terms` will return an `invalid_taxonomy` error. So you may want to add such missing term to your taxonomy:

```
wp_insert_term(
    'Term Name',                      // Customize as you wish
    'lan',
    array(
        'description' => 'Term desc', // Customize as you wish
        'slug'        => 'lan-slug1'  // Customize as you wish
    )
);

// For child term:
$parent_term = term_exists( 'parent_term_id', 'lan' );
$child_term_result = wp_insert_term(
    'Child Term Name',                // Customize as you wish
    'lan',
    array(
        'parent'      => $parent_term['term_id']
        'description' => 'Term desc', // Customize as you wish
        'slug'        => 'lan-slug1'  // Customize as you wish
    )
);

// Add the child term to the post
if ( !is_wp_error( $child_term_result ) ) {
     wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $child_term_result['term_id'], 'lan', true );
}
```

Finally, be sure you execute this code after -at least- the `init` hook of Wordpress. For instance:

```
function parse_my_json() {
    // Your code here
}
add_action('init','parse_my_json');
```

Useful references:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thank you for the well written answer. Unfortunately Im not sure how this will help me since Im already able to insert terms to the database. My issue is how to import child terms assigned to the imported parent term.

Comment: @Fredrik I updated my answer to include child term registering.

Comment: Thank you! It works to import the child terms associated to the parent terms now. The issue is that the child term is not checked to the post (not chosen). I have updated the code above for you to look at

Comment: @Fredrik I guess you should add the child term to your post. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, that did it! Thank you so much!